# How to use a different Json serializer in asmx services?

Tags: .net, json, serialization, asmx

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

The default ResponseFormat instructs the asmx web service to use the built in JavaScriptSerializer, i'm interested in using Json.NET instead.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: In particular, it has a very limited extensibility story.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Unfortunately, not an option (yet).

Comment: Then neither is a different Serializer.

Comment: Agreed about asmx. But having said that json-serialization in wcf has it's own problems (dictionaries as lists of key/values is one example). In wcf you will need to return a stream to customize serialization. So perhaps even WebAPI if possible?